# How to "get" a HTTPS website running?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

I have a website serving several pages that can be reachable via HTTP.

How can I make these sites available via standard HTTPS? (not self-signed). What are the steps? (go to a CA, and then?)

Can someone please describe the full process in steps?

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault.com

Comment: @bitmask I'd say superuser.com

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding if this is on-topic. I think it'll mostly be Apache configuration stuff, which is

Comment: Not superuser. Since the process to accomplish this is OS-agnostic, it would probably go on serverfault, even if the commands are Unix/Linux.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: my personal opinion is: too broad. To be answered correctly, you'd need to explain the steps to create the right type of key-pair and CSR (not Unix/Linux-specific), explain what sort of documents CAs expect in addition to the CSR (could vary widely by CA/country/jurisdiction, not Unix/linux-related either). Then you need to go through the whole apache setup, including virtual hosts, algorithm selection/restriction, redirects maybe, ... which is again (mainly) OS agnostic. I don't think it would stay open at serverfault.

Comment: I would probably vote to close as NARQ (too broad) if it got over to serverfault.

Comment: I suppose most of us could answer, but you don't share any of your research and want us to do your work!

Answer (score 4):

There are many tutorials for `apache` on how to do this.  [This is one of them](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/how-to-configure-https-on-apache-2/).

[Here is another one](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/349)

One thing that you would change if you already have a certificate generated you would copy the certificate files to appropriate locations vs. generating them yourself.

If you are not using `apache` please post the webserver you're using.

Comment: i am using apache

Comment: @LanceBaynes I modified the answer to fit your case better.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is a year old, many CA will provide tools and tutorials to help with this. See [RapidSSL](http://rapidssl.com) - their knowledgebase covers pretty much all common setups.